# python function wont return value

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm new to python and am trying to make a simple paper, rock, scissors game. no matter what I do inside my "lame" function the value of local variable "y" will not be assigned to global variable "var1" or "var2". I have tried using return but cannot get anything to work.

```
#get input (paper, rock scissors from players)
play1 = input("player 1:")
play2 = input("player 2:")

#set value of players score to 0
val1 = 0
val2 = 0

def lame(x, y):
#set value of p, r, s choice, to 1, 2 or 3 
    if x in("p","P"):
        y = y + 1
    elif x in("r","R"):
        y = y + 2
    elif x in("s","S"):
        y = y + 3
    else:
        print("your value was not p, r or s")

#run function "lame" and pass in "play1" choice and 
#retrieve "val1" for that choice
lame(play1, val1)
lame(play2, val2)

def win(x, y):
#subtracts value of players choices to find winner
    dif = x - y
    if dif == 0:
        print("tie game")
    elif dif % 3 == 1:
        print("player 2 wins")
    elif dif % 3 == 2:
        print("player 1 wins")
    else:
        print("logic error")

#call function "win" and pass in results of their choices
win(val1, val2)
```

Comment: Python does not do call by reference with numbers. You'll need to actually set `val1` and `val2` to those values, not `y`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ***wrong*** way to do this:

```
val1 = 0

...

def lame(x):
    global val1
    val1 = result_of_some_calculations_to_do_with(x)
```

The ***right*** way to do this:

```
def lame(x):
    return result_of_some_calculations_to_do_with(x)

val1 = lame(x)
```

Contrary to what L3viathan said in the comments, Python DOES pass variables by reference, but does not ASSIGN variables by reference. In other words:

```
x = 3 # x is 3
y = x # x is 3, y is 3, x is y
y = 4 # x is 3, y is 4, y is REASSIGNED so y is not x
```

That's basically what you were trying to do, passing `val1` to your `lame` function and rebinding it as `y`.

```
val1 = 0 # val1 is 0

def lame(x, y):
    # y is val1
    y = some_calculations_to_do_with(x)
    # y has been REASSIGNED so y is not val1
```

This is important when you pass objects like lists that are mutable (e.g. they can be changed, as opposed to immutable objects line `int` and `str` in Python).

```
val1 = list() # val1 is an empty list

def lame(x,y):
    y.append(x) # append x to y, DO NOT REASSIGN y TO ANYTHING ELSE

lame(1, val1) # val1 is [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted this question I figured it out, and can confirm what Adam Smith has said.

Here is the code I changed to get it working properly:

```
def lame(x): 
    #set value of p, r, s choice to 1, 2 or 3 
    if x in("p","P"):
        return 1
    elif x in("r","R"):
        return 2
    elif x in("s","S"):
        return 3
    else:
        print("your value was not p, r or s")

#run function "lame" and pass in play1 choice and 
#retrive val1 for that choice
val1 = lame(play1)
val2 = lame(play2)
```